# Pass a generic list from controller to view mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, view, controller

I've racked my brain over this for way to long now to I'm deferring to the experts. I know this question has been asked and answered several times but I can't seem to get ANYTHING to work. Here's the scenario: As the title says, I'm trying to pass a list from the controller to the view. I'm using an API that has a method, `"GetInventoryLocations"` whose base type is `List<string>`. In the example below I instantiate a new list and use a `foreach` to loop through the `"InventoryLocation"` programatically casting each item in the collection to a string and adding it to the list I created `"locationlist"`. Finally I assign the list to the `viewdata`. From there I've tried all kinds of things in the view but still can't get it to work. Thanks for any help. Be kind to a junior developer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Moraware.JobTrackerAPI4;
using Evolveware1_0.Models;

namespace Evolveware1_0.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class InventoryController : Controller
    {

        //./Inventory/Locations
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //declare variables for connection string to JobTracker API Service
            var DB = "databasename"; // your DB name here
            var JTURL = "https://" + DB + ".somecompany.net/" + DB + "/";
            var UID = "****"; // your UID here - needs to be an administrator or have the API role
            var PWD = "password"; // your PWD here

            //connect to API
            Connection conn = new Connection(JTURL + "api.aspx", UID, PWD);
            conn.Connect();
            //declaring the jobtracker list (type List<InventoryLocation>)
            var locs = conn.GetInventoryLocations();
            //create a new instance of the strongly typed List<string> from InventoryViewModels
            List<string> locationlist = new List<string>();
            foreach (InventoryLocation l in locs) {
                locationlist.Add(l.ToString());                  
            };
            ViewData["LocationsList"] = locationlist;

            return View();
        }//end ActionResult
    }

};
```

And in the view:

```
@using Evolveware1_0.Models
@using Evolveware1_0.Controllers
@*@model Evolveware1_0.Models.GetLocations*@

@using Evolveware1_0.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Locations</h2>

@foreach (string l in ViewData["LocationList"].ToString())
{
    @l
}
```

Comment: You're a junior developer and you're already using MVC? Nice.

Comment: Do not use `ViewData` - Change your method to `return View(locationlist );` and the view to `@model List<string> @foreach(var l in Model) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a toString() to a list, this will not work. You will need to cast your ViewData to it's proper type, a list of InventoryLocation.

Being that you are using Razor and MVC, I suggest using ViewBag instead, no casting necessary.

In your controller instead of ViewData["LocationList"] = locationlist, initialize a ViewBag property to pass to your view.

```
ViewBag.LocationList = locationlist;
```

Then in your view in your loop just access your ViewBag.LocationList object.

```
@foreach (string l in ViewBag.Locationlist)
{
    @l
}
```

Comment: Just realized I never did thank you for answering this question. I appreciate it.